# camelContext is null in Camel Route Testing while replaceFromWith

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit, apache-camel

I am trying to write JUnit test case to replace my JMS camel route with direct route.
I am trying to replace route "myRoute" with "direct:start". But my camel context is coming as `null`.

```
@CamelSpringBootTest
@SpringBootTest(class = Application.class)
@ContextConfiguration
public class AppTest{
    
    @Autowired
    CamelContext camelContext;
    
    
    public void testMethod(){
    
        AdviceWith.adviceWith(camelContext, "myRoute", routeBuilder -> {
            routeBuilder.replaceFromWith("direct:start");
        });
    }    
}
```

I tried to start the camel context in an `init()` method. But getting below exception from `AdviceWith` class

```
@Before
public void init() throws Exception{
    camelContext.start();    
}
```

`Exception: Getting cannot AdviceRoute as there are no routes`

Comment: Please provide the route that you want to test

Comment: The init method is useless, you can remove it. The `@Test` annotation is missing on your test method. Which version of JUnit do you use 4 or 5?

Comment: as example check this test class https://github.com/apache/camel-spring-boot-examples/blob/main/unit-testing/src/test/java/CamelSpringBootUnitTests.java

Comment: Sorry that i missed to add @Test in this question. But i am using in my project. I am using JUnit 4. I added this code by seeing the example which you shared, But no luck. Still camelContext is null

Comment: The example is in JUnit 5

Comment: Can we able to achieve this in Junit 4?

Comment: JUnit 4 is much too old now, you will have to migrate to JUnit 5

Comment: i tried this example in Junit 5. still getting camelContext as null

Comment: If you want to get an answer to your question, you need to provide all information allowing us to reproduce which is currently not the case. Please read this https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Ever figure it out?